# ')' expected in .jsp

Tags: java, json, jsp

I've got error after I put `$.student[?(@.id=="543020619-3")].register[*].sname` .

But When I deleted it the error was disappear.

*I found out that I have to change String from " " to ' ' and then the error will flew away.*

```js
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" pageEncoding="utf-8" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.List, java.nio.file.*, com.jayway.jsonpath.*" %>


<%
 // 1. อ่านไฟล์เก็บลง String
 String json = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Tuna\\Desktop\\JSONlab\\student.json")), "UTF8");
 
 // 2. แปลข้อมูลจาก String ให้อยู่ในรูปแบบ Object ของ JSON
 Object document = Configuration.defaultConfiguration().jsonProvider().parse(json);

 // 3. ดึงผลลัพธ์ ด้วย JSON Path
 // 3.1 กรณีที่ผลลัพธ์ไม่เป็น Array
 /*String firstName = JsonPath.read(document, "$.student[1].stdName");
 out.println(firstName + "<br><br>");*/
 
        out.println("<br>");
        out.println("ข้อ 1 : JSON Path คือ $...????" + "<br>");
        out.println("<b>" + "ผลลัพธ์" + "</b>");
        out.println("<br>");
        
 // 3.2 กรณีที่ผลลัพธ์เป็น Array
 List<String> name = JsonPath.read(document, "$..stdName");
 for(int i=0; i<name.size(); i++) { 
  out.println(name.get(i) + "<br>");
 } 
        
        
        out.println("<br>");
        out.println("ข้อ 2 : JSON Path คือ $...????" + "<br>");
        out.println("<b>" + "ผลลัพธ์" + "</b>");
        out.println("<br>");
        
        List<String> stdName = JsonPath.read(document, "$.student[?(@.gpa>3.0)].stdName");
 for(int i=0; i<stdName.size(); i++) { 
  out.println(stdName.get(i) + "<br>");
 } 

        
        out.println("<br>");
        out.println("ข้อ 3 : JSON Path คือ $...????" + "<br>");
        out.println("<b>" + "ผลลัพธ์" + "</b>");
        out.println("<br>");
        

        List<String> enroll = JsonPath.read(document, "$.student[?(@.id=="543020619-3")].register[*].sname");
 for(int i=0; i<enroll.size(); i++) { 
  out.println(enroll.get(i) + "<br>");
 } 
        

%>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation. [mcve] applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: java code on jsp. Not a good thing. So what is your problem ?

Answer (score 1):

This String is your problem:

`"$.student[?(@.id=="543020619-3")].register[*].sname"`

You don't escape quotes. Use the following:

`"$.student[?(@.id==\"543020619-3\")].register[*].sname"`

Comment: Thank you for you answer. The error has been gone but it doesn't show any data. I found out that I have to change " " to ' ' .